# Frost bite frozen jade plant with no leaves, please help

Tags: jade, frost

I'm  don't have green fingers. 
I was wondering if you anyone can help. I'm trying to save my jade plant which has lost all its leaves due to frost bite.

Ive got rid of all the damages  mushy leaves and was wondering if it can survive without its leaves. And what I can do to help it survive and grow new leaves?

Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Sorry no photo. I've tried to click on "add picture" but the photo just won't load.

Comment: What part of the world are you in, and did you leave the plant outside? How cold was it for  the plant in terms of temperature? Any chance of a photo of what's left of it? If not, is the stem mushy and soggy?

Comment: Thanks for you're response. It was snowing outside. Stem is not mushy, just the leaves.

Answer (score 1):

If you cut the plant back to healthy stem that is not mushy (was not frozen), a jade plant (i.e. Crassula ovata) will likely sprout again from the living stems.

Comment: Be nice to it afterwards. Give it some sun, and water every couple, three weeks. They are tough plants.